# Express routing: route is ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a NodeJS app that possess multiple routes and subroutes, and use Express to manage them. One of the feature of my app is to display lists of classes, one list of classes per version of a software. For this feature, I have three subroutes in the route 'classes':

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    // default route, redirect to the list of classes of the last version of the software
    // classesGetLastVersion(cb) reads a JSON file and launch callback with last version number
    classesGetLastVersion(function(version) { 
    res.writeHead(301, {
        Location: (req.socket.encrypted ? 'https://' : 'http://') + req.headers.host + '/classes/' + version
    });
    res.end();
});

router.get('/:version', function(req, res){
    // checks the given version in argument, display the list of classes corresponding 
    // to the version (if it exists; else: 404 error page)

    // retrieve the version number specified
    var version = req.params.version;

    // NOTE: we only serve static HTML pages, so here I directly check if the 
    // corresponding file exists
    fs.exists('public/html/classes_' + version + '.html', function(exists){
    if(exists){
        var options = {
            root: path.join(__dirname, __publicRootPath)
        };

        // file exists, serve it
        res.status(200);
        res.set({'Content-type':'text/html'});
        res.sendFile('./html/classes_' + version + '.html', options);
    } else {
        // file doesn't exists, so we'll check if the req.param.version argument corresponds
        // to a class name, in every version of the software

        /** the file 'data/classes.json' has the following architecture:
         * {
         *      "first_version_number": ["className1", "className2", ..., "classNameN"],
         *      "second_version_number" : ["className1", "className2", ..., "classNameN"],
         *      ...
         *      "nth_version_number": ["className1", "className2", ..., "classNameN"]
         * }
         **/
        fs.readFile('data/classes.json', function(err, data){
            if (err) throw err;

            // for clarification purpose
            var className = version;

            var lastVersion,
                jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

            for(var versionName in jsonData){
                console.log('Searching class in version ' + versionName + '...');

                if(jsonData[versionName].lastIndexOf(className) != -1){
                    console.log('Found it! In v' + versionName);
                    lastVersion = versionName;
                } else {
                    console.log('Class is not here :-(');
                }
            }

            if(lastVersion){
                // redirect to the correct class page
                res.writeHead(301, {
                    Location: (req.socket.encrypted ? 'https://' : 'http://') + req.headers.host + '/classes/' + lastVersion + '/' + className
                });
                res.end();
            } else {
                // render 404 - Page not found
                logger.error('404 error - Page not found: public/html/classes_' + version + '.html');
                res.render('errorpages/404.jade', {});
            }
        });
    }
});

router.get('/:version/:name', function(req, res){
    // check the given version AND name of the class, and display the page corresponding
    // to the specified class, if it exists; else: 404 error page

    var version         = req.params.version;
    var className       = req.params.className;
    className = className
        .replace('<', '_').replace('>', '_')
        .replace('%3CT%3E', '_T_')
        .replace('&lt;T$gt;', '_T_');

    console.log('/:version/:className');

    var fileName = path.join('./public/html/class_' + version, className) + '.html';
    fs.exists(fileName, function(exists){
        if(!exists){
            // 404 class not found
            // render 404 - Class not found
            logger.error('404 error - File not found: '  + fileName);
            res.render('errorpages/404_class_not_found.jade', {classname:className});
        } else {
            fileName = path.join('./html/class_' + version, className) + '.html';

            var options = {
                root: path.join(__dirname, __publicRootPath)
            };

            res.status(200);
            res.set({'Content-type':'text/html'});
            res.sendFile(fileName, options);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

So, in principle, nothing's tricky and everything works perfectly, until I tried to implement a new feature: if the user tries to enter the name of a class without specifying its version, I want the **second** route to check in a JSON file if the class exists in one of the version of the software, and display the page corresponding to the class in the last version found.

But the thing is, for a unknown reason, when I try to access /classes/nameOfAClass, it doesn't evaluate the second route, unless I enter complete bullshit for the name of the class. If I give a name of a correct class, it goes immediately in the **third** route (even if I only give it only **ONE** parameter), and gives the last version number of the software for the `:version` parameter, and tries to resolve /classes/lastVersion/nameOfTheClass.

Do you have any idea why it just ignores the second route with only one parameter and goes directly to the third route, giving automatically a valid version number?

**EDITED** -> more code now

To help you help me, here's some additional infos about the app:
At the root of my projet, I have the file server.js, which declares:

```
var app = require('./app');
```

Inside app.js file, I have:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();

app.use(compress());

// Serve static files (css, js, images)
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view cache', true);

//require all routes, index.js is called by default
require('./scripts/router')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Before you ask yourself "why the heck did he do that": that architecture (server file that require app file that itself declares the express app) is needed on the platform I'll have to deploy my app on. Let's continue further in the architecture.

You surely have notices the line `require('./scripts/router')(app);`. In this router folder, I have a single file called "index.js" and a folder named "routes"; this folder contains all my subroutes. The index.js file is as follow:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    // require several subroutes as follow
    app.use('/classes', require('./routes/classes'));
    [...other subroutes...]

    // ERRORS
    // Handle 404
    app.use(function (error, req) {
        req.status(404);
        req.render('errorpages/404.jade', {});
    });

    // Handle 500
    app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
        res.status(500);
        res.render('errorpages/500.jade', {});
    });
};
```

So, in resume:

```
myProjectRooT
|_ server.js
|_ app.js
|_ scripts/
    |_ router/
        |_ index.js
        |_ routes/
            |_ classes.js
            |_ otherRoute.js
            |_ etc...
```

Hope that's helping to understand the problem :-)

**NEW INFO**

HEY! Did you think the problem was strange? Well it got even stranger! As user kanzelm suggested, I console.logged everything (meaning: at the beginning of each route, I do `console.log('nameOfTheRoute');`), and some results were totally unexpected:

1. `localhost:3000/classes`: logs `/:version` and directly goes to `localhost:/classes/lastVersionNumber`; **that's really unexpected**
2. `localhost:3000/classes/aValidVersionNumber`: logs `/:version`, and goes to the correct version page; that's normal
3. `localhost:3000/classes/aNotValidVersionNumber`: logs `/:version`, and looks for a class with the name of the not-valid version number, fails, then redirect to the 404 class not found page; that's normal
4. `localhost:3000/classes/aNotValidClassName`: log `/:version`, looks for a class with this name, fails, and redirect to the 404 class not found page; that's normal
5. `localhost:3000/classes/aValidVersionNumber/aValidClassName`: logs `/:version/:className` and goes to the correct class page; that's normal
6. `localhost:3000/classes/aValidVersionNumber/aNotValidClassName`: logs `/:version/:className` and goes to the 404 class not found page; that's normal

So, here I have two major problems I can't even understand: first, **the root route is totally ignored and is never catched**, even when I try to go to `locahost:3000/classes`; it seems that the url is **auto-completed** with the last valid version number. In theory, that's what I want (look at the code of the very first route), but no console.log from the route, neither from the method `classesGetLastVersion`, are shown. Secondly, the fact that the route `/:version` is catched only when a valid version number is given (which is totally fine) or when a NON-VALID version number/class name is given (which is totally not ok at all) is driving me mad.

Any idea?

Comment: i'm afraid that we are lacking some information here. With just this code, we can't guess why a magic valid version number appears from the wild. Maybe you use some url rewriting tool ? (apache maybe ? )

Comment: I'll edit first post to show you some of the code inside the route ;-) thus, I don't know what you're talking about (url rewrite tool), so I guess I'm not using it, unless unintentionnally :-/

Comment: you're missing the `});` to close `classesGetLastVersion(` in your first route

Comment: also, you haven't shown any route 'classes', how are these "sub routes"? i see routes to `'/'`, `'/:version'`, and `'/:version/:name'` (which should match `"GET /classes/nameOfAClass"`)

Comment: updated! I gave some explanations about how the project is organized, and why I call these "subroutes"

Comment: @Plato : just saw your comment, and of course I'm out of office now... You make me question myself; is it a mistake while copying the code on StackOverflow or is it an original error? ... I'll keep you informed on monday x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, the problem was... THE CACHE.

I created, as a colleague advised me, dummy files to simulate a new version, and a new set of classes to be searched on the app. Then I tried to go to `localhost:3000/classes`, and at my big surprise, I was still going into the same version number than before, meaning "2.1" even if I created a false "2.2" version. Emptying the cache with Ctrl+F5 wasn't doing anything, though. So I checked the "disable cache when developer tools box is open" option in the developer tools page of my browser, and then everything went perfectly fine. Every route were catched correctly and were doing their respective job, as expected.

The solution to bypass the cache has been given to me by user Dan Pantry: put `Cache-Control: 0` into the header of the express response of the different routes.

Comment: To disable/bypass caching, you can append a version querystring to the files you want to bypass the cache on, ala `?v=123` where `123` is the timestamp of the request. If you can't do this, then set `Cache-control` to `0`. Preprocess all of your static assets with a build tool such as gulp and append a content hash to their name so they are not cached either. Be careful with the querystring route as they may lead to undue load on the server (and client, due to extra http requests they may not otherwise need)

Comment: The `Cache-control: 0` solution works just fine for me :-) thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that this block of code is being executed and it is falling back to "lastVerison":

```
        if(lastVersion){
            // redirect to the correct class page
            res.writeHead(301, {
                Location: (req.socket.encrypted ? 'https://' : 'http://') + req.headers.host + '/classes/' + lastVersion + '/' + className
            });
            res.end();
        }
```

Try logging "exists" and seeing if that's true or false.

Comment: Well, that made things even stranger. As you suggested, I inserted at the beginning of each route a `console.log(nameOfTheRoute)` to see where I go when I try to access each route. The result is not what I expected, at all:

    `localhost:3000/classes // logs "/:version"` ; 
    `localhost:3000/classes/aVersionNumber  // logs "/:version"` ; 
    `localhost:3000/classes/aVersionNumber/aValidClassName // logs "/:version/:name"` ; 
    `localhost:3000/classes/aValidClassName // logs "/:version/:name"` ; 
    `localhost:3000/classes/anINVALIDClassName // logs "/:version"`.

Comment: On monday, I'll try to fix the issue by refactoring the code, and use queryString in a single route instead of multiple parametized routes with optionnal parameter.